# How would a system tray application be accomplished on other platforms?

Tags: python, cross-platform, operating-system, wxpython, system-tray

Windows has the "system tray" that houses the clock and alway-running services like MSN, Steam, etc.

I'd like to develop a wxPython tray application but I'm wondering how well this will port to other platforms.  What is the tray equivalent on each platform, and how much manual work would be required to support Windows, OSX and Linux (which shells in particular would be friendliest).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wx is a cross-platform GUI and tools library that supports Win32, Mac OS X, GTK+, X11, Motif, WinCE, and more. And if you use it's classes then your application should work on all these platforms.
For system tray look at wxTaskBarIcon (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtaskbaricon.html#wxtaskbaricon).

Answer (score 3):

Under OS X you have the Status Menu bar - the right-most items are often status-related things (like battery status, WiFi connections, etc).

Try searching for [NSStatusBar](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMenuExtra](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSMenuExtra).  It's almost trivial to turn an application into one that has an NSStatusBar menu and doesn't appear in the Dock.  There are [tutorials](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.02/Menulet/) [around](http://files.semaja2.net/NSStatusItem%20-%20ObjC.html) on how to do it.

Comment: My concern was that MSN appears in the dock and does its notifications by bouncing.  I think that's how I should probably implement mine as well since its primarily a notification service.

Answer (score 2):

For many Linux desktop systems (Gnome, KDE, etc.) a Freedesktop's [SysTray Protocol](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html) is implemented. You can try that if any other solution fails.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it really depends - you got diffrent programming environments there, and some window managers don't even have a tray area. Altho, if you use Gtk (and wx is Gtk really), the [gtk.StatusIcon](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusicon.html) is your friend.

[Here](http://marcin.af.gliwice.pl/if-then-else-20070121143245) are some examples of that (haven't checked if they actually work, but should show you the path).

For `wx` I found some example code [here](http://markmail.org/message/27uwfecsmmpeyoey).

Answer (score 1):

Use Qt: [Qt Systray Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/desktop-systray.html)

That'll show a systray icon on all platforms that Qt runs on and that support such icons. You'll need to come up with a strategy when systray functionality isn't supported, though.